# Draw text with a stroke onto an image in .Net

Tags: .net, graphics, text, gdi

I am currently using the System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString() method in .Net to draw text on top of an image, and then save it to a new file:

```
// define image file paths
string sourceImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/sourceImage.jpg");
string destinationImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/") + "finalImage.jpg";

// create new graphic to draw to
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(200, 200);
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm);

// open and draw image into new graphic
System.Drawing.Image sourceImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourceImagePath, true);
gr.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0);
sourceImage.Dispose();

// write "my text" on center of image
gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BlkCn.ttf"));
// prototype (1)
gr.DrawString("my text", new Font(fontCollection.Families[0], 14, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)), 100, 0, sf);
fontCollection.Dispose();

// save new image
if (File.Exists(destinationImagePath))
{
    File.Delete(destinationImagePath);
}
bm.Save(destinationImagePath);
bm.Dispose();
gr.Dispose();
```

This method of adding text on an image does not provide a way (that I know of) to add a stroke to the text. For example, what I really need to do is add a 2px stroke of a certain color to the text that is written on the image.

How can this be done with the .Net Framework <= v3.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All text has [strokes](http://designorati.com/articles/t1/typography/337/typography-word-of-the-day-stroke.php).

If by stroke you mean outline, then you create a `GraphicsPath` and add the string using [`AddString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142533.aspx), you can then outline the path using DrawPath rather than `FillPath` as used in the example on msdn.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a GraphicsPath object.
        GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();

        // Set up all the string parameters.
        string stringText = "Sample Text";
        FontFamily family = new FontFamily("Arial");
        int fontStyle = (int)FontStyle.Italic;
        int emSize = 96;
        Point origin = new Point(20, 20);
        StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericDefault;

        // Add the string to the path.
        myPath.AddString(stringText,
            family,
            fontStyle,
            emSize,
            origin,
            format);

        //Draw the path to the screen.
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.BlanchedAlmond, myPath);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Brushes.Azure, 2), myPath);
    }
```

If by stroke you mean [strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough), then use the [Strikeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) font style.

If by stroke you mean [serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif), then use a different font.

Comment: Works like a charm! One thing I chose to do is to do the DrawPath call first, and then the FillPath. This way the Drawn path doesn't cover the actual filled path and is more of a stroke.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but try using a [LinearGradientBrush](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223132444/http://bobpowell.net/linear.aspx) instead of a `SolidBrush` in your code.

I'm not sure what you mean by "stroke" in this question, but if you want, say, all pixels on rows 7 and 8 to be red, you can use a `System.Drawing.TextureBrush` instead of a `SolidBrush`.  You would create a `Bitmap` one pixel wide and tall enough for your font (all black except for rows 7 and 8 which would be red), and then use the constructor for `TextureBrush` that takes this `Bitmap` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you could layer two sets of text one atop the other, with the lower layer scaled up just slightly.  Might not work perfectly for all fonts but it's worth a try.